# Optimal prefix-free code design with a complex objective function

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization, coding-theory

We have a long message $m$ to encode. The message is composed of a set of symbols $\{s_i\}$. Let $p_i$ denote the number of appearance of $s_i$ in $m$. We seek to find a prefix-free code for each $s_i$ so as to minimize $\frac{N_0N_1}{N}$, where $N_0$ and $N_1$ denote the number of bits $0$ and $1$ in the coded message, respectively, $N=N_0+N_1$ denotes the length of the coded message. The prefix-free code system is a set of codes where any code is not a prefix of another. Our problem is to find such optimal coding system. Our problem resembles Huffman coding but with a more complex objective function.

Comment: I suspect that you will want to add another constraint to disqualify the following construction: if you have only one symbol, zero bits encode it. Otherwise split the symbols into two non-empty parts, $S_1$ and $S_2$. Use prefix $0^k$ for elements in $S_1$ where $k = \sum_{s_i \in S_2} p_i$ and similarly use prefix $1^n$ for elements in $S_2$ where $n = \sum_{s_i \in S_1} p_i$. Now recurse on both parts. By construction, $N_0 = N_1$ achieving the global minimum of the objective function, but the codes are rather long.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I did not fully understand it. How can you prove that this coding scheme is an optimal solution, e.g., by outperforming Huffman codes.

Comment: If you consider just the bits which distinguish the two children of the root, by construction they contribute $kn$ zeros and $kn$ ones to the encoded message. Then the recursions on the two subtrees continue to maintain the balance $N_0 = N_1$.

Comment: Yes, but why this is the optimal solution?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's a maximum. It was obviously an extremum, and I got the sign of the curve wrong. The minimum would be obtained when wlog $N_0 = 0$, but although that is impossible with a prefix-free code and more than one symbol we can get arbitrarily close to zero by making each symbol's encoding contain exactly one 0 and arbitrarily many 1s. Or just take a Huffman code, prefix $1^a$ to each code, and let $a \to \infty$.

Comment: I am not sure that your policy is optimal. Let $x\triangleq \frac{N_0}{N}$. The objective function can be written as $Nx(1-x)$. Whta you are doing is to let $x$ tend to its minimal, but this leads to a large $N$ as the price. How do your prove that this is in fact the optimum?

Comment: please specify your problem more clearly. Is it the global imbalance between 0 and 1 you are minimizing once you encode all the letters in the order they appear in the message (scaled by division by N)?

Comment: Let me clarify my objective. Let $N$ denote the length of the encoded message in number of bits. Let $x$ denote the fraction of bit $0$ in the coded message. I seek to minimize $Nx(1-x)$. For example, if the coded message is $00111$, then $N=5$ and $x=0.4$, the objective function equals $5*0.4*0.6$.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52082/prefix-free-code-unbalancing-0-and-1-bits  .

Answer (score 0):

Proof for 3 symbols: We can assume that the codes are 0, 10, 11, any other choice is suboptimal.
Let the occurrences be $p_1\le p_2\le p_3$. We have 3 sensible options for the encodings:

Option 1. $p_1$: 10, $p_2$: 0, $p_3$: 11
After normalization, $N_0=p_1+p_2$, $N_1=p_1+2p_3$, $N=2p_1+p_2+2p_3=2-p_2$.
The objective function is $\frac{(p_1+p_2)(p_1+2p_3)}{2p_1+p_2+2p_3}$.

Option 2. $p_1$: 10, $p_2$: 11, $p_3$: 0
After normalization, $N_0=p_1+p_3$, $N_1=p_1+2p_2$, $N=2p_1+2p_2+p_3=2-p_3$.
The objective function is $\frac{(p_1+p_3)(p_1+2p_2)}{2p_1+2p_2+p_3}$.

Option 3. $p_1$: 11, $p_2$: 10, $p_3$: 0
After normalization, $N_0=p_2+p_3$, $N_1=2p_1+p_2$, $N=2p_1+2p_2+p_3=2-p_3$.
The objective function is $\frac{(p_2+p_3)(2p_1+p_2)}{2p_1+2p_2+p_3}$.

These are not compared so easily.
To compare the last two, the denominators are the same, so using $p_3=1-p_1-p_2$, so we get

$$(1-p_2)(p_1+2p_2)~VS~(1-p_1)(2p_1+p_2)$$
$$p_2-p_2(p_1+2p_2)~VS~p_1-p_1(2p_1+p_2)$$
$$p_2(p_3-p_2)~VS~p_1(p_3-p_1)$$

So we need to choose between options 2 and 3 depending on whether $p_1$ or $p_2$ is closer to $p_3/2$.

Comparing the other options leads to more complicated calculations, so your problem won't have a nice and simple answer, like the Huffman coding, but rather requires the solution of several inequalities.

Comment: I agree with you that my problem does not admit a simple answer, but my objective can also be finding a polynomial time algorithm computing the optimal coding policy.

Comment: Polynomial in $m$?

Comment: Maybe it is not correct to use "polynomial" in this problem, As far I as understand, the complexity does not depend on $m$, as the objective function only contains the statistics of $m$, i.e., portions of $0$ and $1$ bits in the message. Let me restate my problem: I seek an algorithm to compute an optimal coding scheme (like huffman algorithm). Maybe a naive approach is to search exhaustively the possible code combinations, but is there a better algorithm, e.g., relying on some sort of dynamic programming... This is what I am lokking for.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Apart from eliminating a few trivial cases, like in the above solution, I don't really see how the exhaustive search could be sped up.

Comment: I agree with you. In fact I have been sitting down quite some time thinking over the problem. My feeling was to look at some sort of dynamic programming based structure or like HUffman tree, but the objective function in my case is more complex. Another issue which might be trivial, in your simple 3-symbol example, you implicitly assume that we will not choose longer codes, e.g., 3 bits, is it trivial to prove?

Comment: Yes, that is easy in this case: Since we have at least two prefix-free codewords, some of them will contain a 0 and a 1. Then we can assume without loss of generality that one of the codewords is 0. The other two start with a 1. As one of them has a 0 in it, and the other one has another 1 in it, we can assume that they are 10 and 11, to make them as short as possible.

Comment: Thank you. A tricky point is that in Huffman setting, more frequent symbol leads to shorter code, but this property does not hold in the new problem.

Comment: I think that doing a case analysis for 4 symbols could shed more light on the problem, because in that case there are more binary trees of interest: either you use 00, 01, 10, 11, or 0, 10, 110, 111, or 0, 11, 100, 101.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will have a try. My feeling is that once the tree is given, it should be feasible to map each symbol to each leaf, but the main difficulty is that there are an exponential number of possible trees, unlike the Huffman case where the tree is constructed by Huffman algo.